# Objective-C YouTube API - creating video object from URL

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am given a list of youtube IDs. For each of this IDS, I want to use the **YouTube API** to get the title, duration, and thumbnail. I then want the user to be able to click these thumbnails which takes them to a UIWebView where they can watch the video.

I'm really stuck on how I can actually create a video object from the ID. I dont really understand the process in given in [Google's sample code](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m), they get the title based on a playlist. I dont want it based on a playlist, I want it based on a stand-alone ID or URL.

Using a playlist query, the code uses:

```
  if ([playlistID length] > 0) {
GTLServiceYouTube *service = self.youTubeService;

GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"snippet,contentDetails"];
query.playlistId = playlistID;
query.maxResults = 50;

_playlistItemListTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                   GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItemList,
                                                   NSError *error) {
   // Callback
   _playlistItemList = playlistItemList;
   _playlistFetchError = error;
   _playlistItemListTicket = nil;

   [self updateUI];
 }];
  }
```

Which I understand, but looking through **GTLQueryYouTube** I cant see anything that relates to a single video.
Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used:

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
// Services which do not require sign-in may need an API key from the
service.APIKey = @"myKey";

GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosListWithPart:@"id, snippet, fileDetails"];
query.identifier = @"xxxxxxxxxx, yyyyyyyyyy";

GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                   // This callback block is run when the fetch completes
                                   if (error == nil) {
                                       GTLYouTubeSearchListResponse *products = object;
                                       // iteration of items and subscript access to items.
                                       for (GTLYouTubeSearchResult *item in products) {

                                           //NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [item JSONValueForKey:@"id"];
                                           GTLYouTubeThumbnailDetails *thumbnails = item.snippet.thumbnails;
                                           GTLYouTubeThumbnail *thumbnail = thumbnails.high;

                                           [imageArray addObject:thumbnail.url];
                                           [titleArray addObject:item.snippet.title];

                                           //NSLog(@"id: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"videoId"]);
                                           //NSLog(@"Title: %@", item.snippet.title);

                                       }
                                   }else{
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

                                   }
                                   [self.thumbnailView reloadData];
                               }];
```

So created a **queryForVideosListWithPart** using a list of video ids separated by comma

Comment: Can you help me, I add fileDetails on query but on response item.fileDetails still return nil